# Get data from JSON in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-scope

I am beginner in AngularJS and trying to get the data from .json file but I am not getting it at front side... anybody can tell me how can I find it on client side. Although I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080331/angularjs-get-data-from-json) but couldn't find the desired result.

**records.json**

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "Dawn",
    "lastName" : "Cassidy",
    "gender"   : "Female",
    "salary"   : 35000
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Paul",
    "lastName": "Hastings",
    "gender": "Male",
    "salary": 325000
  },
  {
    "firstName": "steve",
    "lastName": "payne",
    "gender": "Male",
    "salary": 30000
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Tina",
    "lastName": "Duggan",
    "gender": "Female",
    "salary": 35000
  }
]
```

**Script.js**

```
app.controller("dataController", function ($scope, $http) {
    var url = "data/records.josn";
    $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
        $scope.employees = response;
    });
});
```

**FirstPage.cshtml**

```
<div ng-controller="dataController">
           <table style="width:500px; border:2px solid black;">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="text-align:left">
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | orderBy: '-salary'">
                        <td>{{ employee.firstName | uppercase }}</td>
                        <td>{{ employee.lastName | lowercase }}</td>
                        <td>{{ employee.gender }}</td>
                        <td>{{ employee.salary | currency: "$" }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to confirm you're getting a response from GETing the JSON file?

Comment: I am getting "data/records.json" in string form in url.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in code used "josn" instead of "json".

```
app.controller("dataController", function ($scope, $http) {
    var url = "data/records.json";
    $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
        $scope.employees = response;
    });
});
```

Comment: is records.json loading ( status 200) in network tab (chrome dev tools)